# PHP check if session is still valid

Tags: php, session, session-state

I have a PHP application that uses sessions for retaining users information/permissions etc as that user navigates through the application.  I've now been asked to configure the system to prevent the same user from logging in more than once. I can't use cookies.

As part of my authentication process, I track when a user logs in etc and so thought of capturing the users PHP session value (using `session_id()`), store that in the database and then nullify that field when the user selects to logout (or gets automatically logged out through inactivity). With an updated login process this should be possible.

I like this approach, it's pretty clean but has the drawback of not nullifying the sessionID if the user closes their browser without cleanly logging out. So then I got to thinking: if there **is** a value in the sessionid, why not check to see if PHP deems it still to be valid?

Now from memory I seem to remember a PHP function that will tell me whether or not a particular session is still valid, or not. I thought that this was `session_id()` but I don't think that's the case, as that gets or sets the current session.  From what I remember, the function would check the server's session.save_path (/var/lib/php/sessions using Ubuntu and a default PHP.ini) to see if the file is still valid* and report back accordingly... but I can't seem to find that function.

Can anyone assist me here?

*I appreciate that PHPs garbage collection leaves a lot to be desired

Comment: Use database handler, not filesystem handler. Then you can control the session using a PHP wrapper mechanism of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is such function to check the *session status* whether it is active, disabled or do not exists

### `session_status()`

This functions return you the values as

- PHP_SESSION_DISABLED if sessions are disabled.
- PHP_SESSION_NONE if sessions are enabled, but none exists.
- PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE if sessions are enabled, and one exists.

For more details regarding this function [Click Here](https://www.php.net/session_status)

Comment: how do you pass the session value though? ```session_status()``` doesn't take any parameters. Remember I'm pulling a session value from the database and need to ascertain if it's still valid. I'm not checking the current session

Comment: It returns you false on disactive and true on active so you can just set  the condition as `if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE)`

Comment: Then if true it means session is active.

Comment: Remember I'm pulling a session value from the database and need to ascertain if it's still valid. I'm not checking the current session

Comment: Yes if your session in the database varies it will return you the exact status for it.

Comment: Please read the documentation provided you will get all your doubts cleared.

Comment: I think you mean:
session_id($valueFromDatabase);  // sets the current session to that from the database
session_status(); // see the status

Using both commands?

Comment: Yes excatly after getting the session_id() you can check the status for that .